# How to find enclosing block in vim?

Tags: vim

Searching backwards for `{` is finding sibling blocks.

The file is properly indented, possibly this can be done by moving upwards from one character before (^) until first non-whitespace character.

Is there any other way?

Eg:

```
if (some condition) {
  for (;;) {

  }
  some statements;
  here you're;
  while (some condition) {

  }
}
```

Is there a way to navigate from "here you're" to if?

I was thinking of placing cursor before "here you're" and call a function which will move cursor up until it finds non-whitespace character.

Comment: I don't get what you want exactly. Can yuo give an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press (cursor on any char of `here you're` line)

```
[{
```

This is  exactly what you are looking for. For detailed info, `:h [{`, or `:h motion.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>%</kbd> is the correct way to do that.

Comment: Only if you're in block end } you can use %

Comment: As you can see in your example, the `{` can be anywhere in the line. It is not necessary that it will be the first character of that line.

Comment: The aim is to reach the line where the block starts, not necessarily {

Comment: `%` is **not** the correct way to do that. at least not for OP's requirement. `%` brings you to the "pair". if cursor on `while`, `%` will move to `(`, not backwards to the first `{`

Answer (score 1):

Your example uses C code, which uses braces (<kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd>) for grouping, so the following suggestion is not directly useful.  For many languages that use matching patterns for grouping (such as `if` and `fi` in shell scripts, `<table>` and `</table>` in HTML, for example) my `matchit.vim` script, part of the standard vim distribution, extends <kbd>%</kbd> and defines additional motions:

- <kbd>g%</kbd>:  cycle backwards
- <kbd>[%</kbd>:  start of enclosing block (like the current question)
- <kbd>]%</kbd>:  end of enclosing block
- <kbd>a%</kbd>:  (Visual mode only) select the matching block

  :help matchit-install